# pytest-html add custom test results to report

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I'm using pytest0html to generate my html report. my test record tested values and I need to show a table of this values with prettytable in case of success. 
I think that i need to implement this hook:

```
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_html(report, data):
    if report.passed:
        del data[:]
        data.append(my_pretty_table_string)
        # or data.append(report.extra.text)
```

But how to pass my_pretty_table_string to the hook function or how to edit report.extra.text from my test function ?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `my_pretty_table_string` stored and generated?

Please give more details to your question so we can help :)

`pytest_html_results_table_html` gets `report` object from `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook. So you need to implement `pytest_runtest_makereport` to add your data to the result at 'call' step.

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
   outcome = yield # get makereport outcome
   if call.when == 'call':
      outcome.result.my_data = <your data object goes here>
```

then you can access `report.my_data` in `pytest_html_results_table_html` hook.

Alex